# Identifying Parallel line segments at fixed distance in same shapefile layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a single, polyline shapefile for a utility grid.  This shapefile displays overbuild lines by offsetting them from each other approximately 40 feet, and running the lines parallel to their true location.

[image: An example of the parallel line segments]

I am trying to identify those areas where I have parallel lines within 40 feet, likely meaning they occupy the same corridor.

How do I do this using geoprocessing functions, as opposed to Python scripts?

Comment: Geoprocessing functions are exposed as Python functions, so your meaning is unclear.  Do you just want to use the graphical user interface (GUI)? You'll need to [Edit] the question to specify which version of ArcGIS is in use.

Comment: Technically, what you are describing is buffering 40 feet (without dissolving) and spatially joining the lines "completely within the buffer" to identify which buffers completely contain more than one line, then possibly using collapse parallel lines to centerlines tool to create a single line...but there are going to be so many issues with this dataset that requires manual correction (line fragments where two parallel lines do not stop and start at the same location, short fragments that are not parallel but still within the buffer, topology errors create by collapsing the lines).